# Conversão e Agrupamento de Linhas em colunas dinamicamente em Oracle

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, pivot

**Contexto:**

> Tenho um **Projeto** com varias **Versões** de aplicativos que serão
>   desenvolvidas, cada Versão vários Requisito de Novas Funcionalidades
>   (NF), cada NF com varias alterações de Códigos em vários Repositórios.
>   Além disto, essas NF podem conter alterações nos mesmos repositórios.

**Problema:**

> A **consulta 1** que faço no banco está trazendo a Versão NF e Repositório,
>   entretanto preciso mapear o impacto de e cruzar
>   informações para saber o impacto de uma versão em outra, e de uma NF
>   em outra NF ou Versão, conforme **Figura 1**.

**Consulta 1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT versao
               ,nf
               ,repositorio
          FROM tabeladoprojeto
         WHERE projeto = 1
```

**Resultado - Consulta 1:**

```
VERSAO      NF      REPOSITORIO
VER.D.1.0.0 56438   REPOSITORIO_G
VER.D.1.0.0 56438   REPOSITORIO_D
VER.F.1.0.0 56976   REPOSITORIO_F
VER.F.1.0.0 56976   REPOSITORIO_G
VER.F.1.0.0 56976   REPOSITORIO_B
VER.D.1.0.0 57049   REPOSITORIO_H
VER.D.1.0.0 57049   REPOSITORIO_E
VER.D.1.0.0 57049   REPOSITORIO_D
VER.D.1.0.0 57054   REPOSITORIO_H
VER.D.1.0.0 57054   REPOSITORIO_E
VER.D.1.0.0 57054   REPOSITORIO_D
VER.D.1.0.0 57054   REPOSITORIO_J
VER.D.1.0.0 57054   REPOSITORIO_A
VER.D.1.0.0 57056   REPOSITORIO_C
VER.D.1.0.0 57056   REPOSITORIO_E
VER.D.1.0.0 57056   REPOSITORIO_F
VER.D.1.0.0 57056   REPOSITORIO_H
VER.D.1.0.0 57157   REPOSITORIO_E
VER.D.1.0.0 57157   REPOSITORIO_A
VER.C.1.0.0 57892   REPOSITORIO_A
VER.C.1.0.0 57892   REPOSITORIO_B
VER.F.1.0.0 57942   REPOSITORIO_E
VER.F.1.0.0 57942   REPOSITORIO_G
VER.F.1.0.0 57942   REPOSITORIO_F
VER.F.1.0.0 58256   REPOSITORIO_F
VER.D.1.0.0 58447   REPOSITORIO_E
VER.D.1.0.0 58447   REPOSITORIO_D
VER.D.1.0.0 58576   REPOSITORIO_I
VER.D.1.0.0 58576   REPOSITORIO_E
VER.D.1.0.0 58576   REPOSITORIO_D
VER.C.1.0.0 58951   REPOSITORIO_I
VER.C.1.0.0 58951   REPOSITORIO_C
VER.C.1.0.0 58951   REPOSITORIO_B
VER.C.1.0.0 58951   REPOSITORIO_E
```

**Figura 1:**
[image: Versões com varias NF e varias alterações em Repositórios diferentes]
*Figura 1 - Representa Versões com varias NF e varias alterações em Repositórios diferentes, o número 1 indica alteração.*

**Necessidade:**

> Conforme **Consulta 2** abaixo, utilizo o `pivot`para fazer isso,
>   porém não é dinâmico, ou seja, tenho que informar para quais são as
>   colunas, que serão transformadas em linhas e agrupadas. Isso da
>   bastante trabalho fazer manualmente, pois o que passei foi exemplo, no
>   contexto real é muito mais complexo, podendo ter 30 NF, e alterações
>   em 40 repositórios.
>
> Pensando que **Consulta 1** tenho os repositórios necessários, queria
>   se fosse possível fazer de forma dinâmica o retorno da consulta 2,
>   conforme abaixo.

**Consulta 2:**

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT versao
                   ,nf
                   ,repositorio
              FROM tabeladoprojeto
             WHERE projeto = 1) 
pivot
(
 COUNT(repositorio) FOR repositorio IN
 ('REPOSITORIO_G','REPOSITORIO_D','REPOSITORIO_F','REPOSITORIO_B','REPOSITORIO_H','REPOSITORIO_E','REPOSITORIO_J','REPOSITORIO_A','REPOSITORIO_C','REPOSITORIO_I')
)
```

**Resultado - Consulta 2:**

```
VER.C.1.0.0 57892   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
VER.C.1.0.0 58951   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
VER.D.1.0.0 57049   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0    
VER.D.1.0.0 57157   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0  
VER.D.1.0.0 58447   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0  
VER.D.1.0.0 57056   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1  
VER.D.1.0.0 56438   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0  
VER.D.1.0.0 57054   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0  
VER.F.1.0.0 57942   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0  
VER.F.1.0.0 56976   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0  
VER.F.1.0.0 58256   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

Os dados acima são exemplos podendo não estar de acordo um com o outro.

Muito obrigado

Comment: David.. Algo como isto não resolveria seu problema? [dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql). Deixaria os repositórios de maneira dinâmica. Se bem entendi o problema.

Comment: @FernandoA.W., realizei os testes, a primeira resposta a que está marcada como resolvida, já conhecia, porém não posso trabalhar com XML. A Terceira resposta testei e não funcionou, no artigo relatado pelo autor enfrento o mesmo erro que as pessoas. Já a segunda resposta do [Usuário](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2179919/user2179919) atende em partes, ela gera a lista de repositorios de maneira mais rápida, ajuda, mas não resolve efetivamente, muito obrigado!

Comment: Perfeito, que bom que te ajudou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme comentário do [Fernando A.W](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15268/fernando-a-w) sobre uma resposta no [so] da pergunta [Dynamic pivot in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql) do [Usuário](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2179919/user2179919). Ajuda em partes, vamos a explicação.

Conforma `select` abaixo, é executado para gerar as colunas necessárias para o `pivot` fazer a conversão de linhas em colunas, dessa forma melhorando o processo, porém não resolvendo efetivamente.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT listagg('''' || repositorio || ''' AS ' || repositorio,',') within GROUP(ORDER BY repositorio) AS temp_in_statement
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT repositorio
          FROM (SELECT repositorio
                  FROM tabeladoprojeto
                 WHERE projeto = 1))
```

O retorno é algo assim:

```
'REPOSITORIO_A' as REPOSITORIO_A,'REPOSITORIO_B' as REPOSITORIO_B,'REPOSITORIO_C' as REPOSITORIO_C
```

O select final passando a entrada do retorno acima:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT versao
                   ,nf
                   ,repositorio
              FROM tabeladoprojeto
             WHERE projeto = 1) 
pivot
(
 COUNT(repositorio) FOR repositorio IN
 (&temp_in_statement)
)
```

Embora tenha limitação 4000 bytes para concatenar uma sequencia, em meus testes abrange todos repositórios.