# Consulta para transformar colunas em registros

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Tenho uma consulta que envolve várias tabelas no Oracle, e retorna um número grande de colunas. Eu queria que ao invés de retornar os registros dessa consulta, me retornasse as colunas do select como registros.

Um exemplo de como mais ou menos é a consulta atual:

```
SELECT
tab1.campo1 'tab1.campo1',
tab1.campo2 'tab1.campo2',
tab1.campo3 'tab1.campo3',
tab2.campo1 'tab2.campo1',
tab2.campo2 'tab2.campo2',
tab2.campo3 'tab2.campo3',
tab3.campo1 'tab3.campo1',
tab3.campo2 'tab3.campo2',
tab3.campo3 'tab3.campo3',
tab4.campo1 'tab4.campo1',
tab4.campo2 'tab4.campo2',
tab4.campo3 'tab4.campo3'
FROM
tabela1 tab1,
tabela2 tab2, 
tabela3 tab3,
tabela4 tab4
WHERE
tab1.campo2 = tab2.campo1
and tab2.campo3 = tab4.campo1
and tab1.campo3 = tab3.campo1
```

Novamente, preciso listar dessas colunas como linhas.

Tentei usar o Unpivot, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Vê se ajuda, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104776/convers%C3%A3o-e-agrupamento-de-linhas-em-colunas-dinamicamente-em-oracle

Comment: Esses exemplos não são em Oracle, mas talvez possam te ajudar: 1 - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135025/como-converter-resultado-de-pesquisa-no-mysql-em-colunas/135035#135035  2 - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131780/como-transfomar-a-linha-de-uma-tabela-em-coluna/131796#131796

Comment: Ambos ajudaram. Consegui listar alguma coisa. Obrigado.

Comment: @Alexandre, poderia adicionar a solução como resposta para o problema?

Comment: SELECT COLUNA1 FROM TABELA1 UNION SELECT COLUNA2 FROM TABELA1 UNION ... SELECT COLUNAN FROM TABELA1 UNION SELECT COLUNA1 FROM TABELAN  ,... UNION SELECT COLUNAN FROM TABELAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foi encontrada a seguinte solução para resolver esse problema e retornar as colunas.

```
SELECT
    COLUNA, 
    VALOR 
FROM(
    SELECT
        tab1.campo1 'tab1.campo1',
        tab1.campo2 'tab1.campo2',
        tab1.campo3 'tab1.campo3',
        tab2.campo1 'tab2.campo1',
        tab2.campo2 'tab2.campo2',
        tab2.campo3 'tab2.campo3',
        tab3.campo1 'tab3.campo1',
        tab3.campo2 'tab3.campo2',
        tab3.campo3 'tab3.campo3',
        tab4.campo1 'tab4.campo1',
        tab4.campo2 'tab4.campo2',
        tab4.campo3 'tab4.campo3'
    FROM
        tabela1 tab1,
        tabela2 tab2, 
        tabela3 tab3,
        tabela4 tab4
    WHERE
        tab1.campo2 = tab2.campo1
        and tab2.campo3 = tab4.campo1
        and tab1.campo3 = tab3.campo1
)
UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS(
    VALOR FOR COLUNA IN 
    (
        tab1.campo1,
        tab1.campo2,
        tab1.campo3,
        tab2.campo3,
        tab2.campo2,
        tab2.campo3,
        tab3.campo1,
        tab3.campo2,
        tab3.campo3,
        tab4.campo1,
        tab4.campo2,
        tab4.campo3
    )
)
```

Está retornando alguns registros. Um problema que pode ocorrer é por causa de diferente tipagens de colunas. Então uma resolução para isso seria usar o TO_CHAR no select para deixar todas as colunas como string.

Caso a consulta normal retorne mais de 1 linha, é possível que haja a repetição das colunas no resultado com o unpivot. Por isso seria ideal garantir que não retorne mais de 1 registro, assim vai listar todas as colunas da consulta sem duplicação.

Esse problema tem o objetivo apenas de poder pegar as colunas, sendo os valores do select normal dispensáveis aqui.